# iPhone: How to access multiple XMLs in the same view

Tags: iphone

I am trying to read data from two different XML's to populate fields of my View in iPhone.

Is there any way to read multiple XML's in the same view? I can read and parse a single XML.

Thanks

//Using the NSXML Parser

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{
[webData setLength:0];
}


-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
[webData appendData:data];       
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{NSLog(@"Connection Error");
[connection release];
[webData release];       
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
NSLog(@"Done, Received bytes: %d",[webData length]);
NSString *theXML =[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[webData mutableBytes]length:[webData length]encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"XML value %@",theXML);
         [theXML release];
         if (xmlParser) {
                 [xmlParser release];
         }

         xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithData:webData];
         [xmlParser setDelegate:self];
         [xmlParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:YES];
         [xmlParser parse];
         [connection release];
         [webData release];
}

- (void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser{
         NSLog(@"found file and started parsing");

         //colorTypes = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
         propertyCategories = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
}


-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString
*)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary
*)attributeDict{
         if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"GetCommonCodeByCatgResult"]) {
         }

         if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"SvcCommonCode"]) {

                 aCategory =[[Category alloc]init];

                 aCategory.CMCodeDesc = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"CMCodeDesc"];
                 }

}

-(void)parser: (NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{

         if (!currentElementValue)
                 currentElementValue =[[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:string];
         else
                 [currentElementValue appendString:string];


}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString
*)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{

         if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"GetCommonCodeByCatgResult"]) {
         [itemCategoryList reloadAllComponents];
     //[colorList reloadAllComponents];
         return;
         }
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"SvcCommonCode"]) {

    [propertyCategories addObject:aCategory.CMCodeDesc];
//[colorTypes addObject: aCategory.CMCodeDesc];
    [aCategory release];
        aCategory =nil;

 }

else
[aCategory setValue:currentElementValue forKey:elementName];
 [currentElementValue release];
currentElementValue = nil;

}
```

Comment: Which XML parser do you use? What code do you use to parse the XML? Without this information, it's highly unlikely someone will answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Boolean, name it  **isParsingNextString**  to parse a different string and elements.

```
//in viewDidLoad
 isParsingNextString = NO;

//put this inside your begin parsing method
if (isParsingNextString == NO) {
     //parse 1st string URL
}

if (isParsingNextString == YES) {
     //parse 2nd string URL
}

//when your document finishes set the bool to yes    
//now restart your parser inside an if statement so you dont have a parsing loop
if(isParsingNextString == NO) {  
  isParsingNextString = YES;  
  [self parseXML];
}
```

Comment: Thanks Louie I shall try implementing it.

Comment: Hey Louie, the 2nd XML does not get parsed and the application just crashes. There are no errors on the console either. Any suggestions?

Comment: make sure you are not releasing your parser too early, and make sure you have accounted for the different element types in your 2nd string.